# Collada (*.dae) file structure and Pycollada

Tags: python, graphics, rendering, collada, 3d-modelling

I am trying to understand the structure of a collada file. Specifically I am using the library pycollada (https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada). I have 2 questions.

**Question 1**:

Having a look to the tutorial to create a file from scratch (http://pycollada.github.io/creating.html), what I don't understand is the structure of the Collada object. In particular, having a look to the following lines of code seems that the mesh is used to create the geometry, and the geometry is included in the mesh:

```
>>> mesh = Collada()
>>> geom = geometry.Geometry(mesh, "geometry0", "mycube", [vert_src, normal_src])
```

and few lines after

```
>>> triset = geom.createTriangleSet(indices, input_list, "materialref")
>>> geom.primitives.append(triset)
>>> mesh.geometries.append(geom)
```

Someone has a clear structure of a Collada file? Possibly a visual representation to understand what is where.

**Question 2**:

If I want to have 2 different objects (here I mean 2 different 3D objects inside of the Collada file, e.g. a cube and a sphere) where should I add the second one? Is a second geometry object inside of the mesh, or maybe a second TriangleSet inside of the geometry, or is defined in a different way?

Answer (score 3):

The `<geometry>` element in COLLADA is the container of the information that describes a geometric shape. There are possible representations of 3D objects when creating digital assets. And polygonal mesh is only one of these representation possibilities. Another possibility could be for example `<brep>`.

Polygon-based  geometry descriptions are  included  as  child  elements of `<mesh>` element under the `<geometry>`. These elements are `<lines>`, `<linestrips>`, `<polygons>`, `<polylists>`, `<triangles>`, `<trifans>` and `<tristrips>`.

So the structure looks like: I have a `<geometry>` -> Which kind of? -> i.e. `<mesh>` -> Contains which polygon-based geometries? -> i.e. `<triangles>`
Let me show you the internal structure of the geometry in COLLADA:

[image: Structure of triangle-based mesh geometry in COLLADA]

You can define positions of the points in 3D space in the `<source>` element with `<float_array>` and your indices under `<p>` element under `<triangles>`. `<p>` element defines not only the vertices but also the normals in this example.

For your second question, you can define it as a second `<geometry>` in your geometry library, or a part of the mesh under the  element. But if you have to use them later separated from each other, for example you want to create 2 instances of the cube, one is green another is blue, and 1 instance of the sphere, you should not do it under the same mesh. You should define them as two separated geometry objects. It depends on your case.

Comment: Can you explain the content of the float array? Why does it hve `60` counts and what do these represent? Also what do the numbers between the `<p>` tag represent?

Comment: @VivekBagaria To be clear again, float array (in this context) defines positions of the points in 3D space, that means X,Y,Z values of a point. 60 is the amount of points. In this example the position of the first point is -3000, -3000,0. p defines indices, first for vertex indices and second for normal indices. In this example 17 is the index of first point, again comes 17 as the index of normal (that means same point in the universe), then comes 15 as the second point and 15 again as second normal and so on.